# What is the difference between saying something like root->data and root.data?

Tags: syntax

As the title states, what is the difference between -> and .
I thought they were the same thing?

Answer (score 6):

These are different operators, though related.

In C, `.` is field selection, and `->` combines pointer dereference and field selection.  So `a->b` is equivalent to `(*a).b` or more correctly `(*(a)).b`.

Many languages don't have both `.` and `->`.  In C# and Java, for example, which don't have `->`, the `.` operator does both dereference and field selection as in `->` in C.  However, in C# and Java, `.` also does selection from a namespace, which does not involve dereferencing (more like C++'s `::` operator).

---

Note: C# does have an `unsafe` construct that allows for unsafe/raw pointers, and also does actually have the `->` operator to work with them.  However, you won't encounter `->` unless you're working in `unsafe` code.

Comment: In C# and Java (as of Java 8) `->` is used in lambdas

Comment: @yitzih In C# at least, `->` remains a pointer dereference like C++ when you compile as unsafe. Lambdas are `=>`.

Comment: @yitzih, good catch.  I'm so used to C# and Javascript, which both use `=>` for lambdas, that I forgot Java uses `->` for that!